# How to use credentialID to make git commits work when using repo to download code in pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Part of the pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'slave3' }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'GITCHOICE', choices: ['tag', 'build'], description: 'Select TAG or BUILD')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Preparation') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'printenv'
                    cleanWs()
                    def CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH = "${params.CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH}"
                    if (CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH != 'master') {
                        CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH = "${params.CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH}"
                    }
                    sh "repo init -b ${CUSTOM_REPO_BRANCH} -u ssh://git@192.168.0.3/${CUSTOM_REPO_PROJECT}"
                    sh "repo sync" 
            }
        }

        stage('tag') {
            when { expression { params.GITCHOICE == 'tag' } }
            steps {
                script {
                    def microservices = ['goodwx', 'proxy', 'audit']
                    for (int i = 0; i < microservices.size(); ++i) {
                        sh "cd $WORKSPACE/${microservices[i]} && git tag ${TAG_VERSION} && git push manifests ${TAG_VERSION}"
                    }
                    sh "cd $WORKSPACE/.repo/manifests/ && sed -i 's#deploy#refs/tags/${TAG_VERSION}#g' default.xml && git add default.xml && git commit -m 'modify default.xml to add tag' && git push origin && git tag ${TAG_VERSION} && git push origin ${TAG_VERSION}"
            }
            }
        }
```

I am using repo in pipeline to download the code, but when I execute to git commit command, It will prompt the following message:

```
git commit -m "add default.xml"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@1d9df917fea7.(none)')
```

I created the git credentialID on jenkins, my question is where in the pipeline do I insert the credentialID so that git commits don't report the above prompts